# Is there a term for when high-level languages are compiled to lower-level ones (such as C)?

Tags: compilation, programming-languages, terminology

I have looked for an answer to this question and cannot seem to find one. I am looking for the term which refers to programming languages that are compiled to other programming languages in an intermediate stage. Examples would be Haskell, Scheme, Common Lisp, and ATS, which all compile down to some variation of C. I could swear I remember studying this briefly at some point, and seeing this phenomenon labeled as something specific. I just can't remember what.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant term is "transcompiling", but it refers to compiling to *any* language, not necessarily just a lower-level one.

Comment: Hmm . . . that isn't quite what I was looking for. The label I was speaking of was specifically for higher-to-lower level compilation, as a step along the way to machine code. I may be imagining such a definition ever existed, but I don't think so. I will read about transcompiling and see if it leads me to it. Thanks for the hint.